# freemarker - variable name with dot

Tags: java, escaping, freemarker

Is it possible to refer a variable that contains dot in a freemarker template? (or '-' character)

e.g.:

Main.java:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, TemplateException {
        Configuration freemarkerConfig = new Configuration();
        freemarkerConfig.setClassForTemplateLoading(Main.class, "");
        Template template = freemarkerConfig.getTemplate("template.ftl");

        Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();
        data.put("variable.name", "value");

        Writer out = new StringWriter();
        template.process(data, out);
        System.out.println(out.toString());
    }
}
```

template.ftl:

```
${variable.name}
```

This code throws exception:

```
The following has evaluated to null or missing:
==> variable  [in template "template.ftl" at line 1, column 3]
```

Is it possible to refer the variable "variable.name" in the tempalte file?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It is possible with this syntax:

```
${.data_model["variable.name"]}
```

[`.data_model`](http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_specvar.html) is a special variable you can use to access the data-model directly.

Comment: This works fine for a non nested variable, and I am able to escape the period (dot).

How can we make it work for a nested scenario, where one of the period is for describing the hierarchy, which other is in the name which we wish to escape.

${person.a.g.e}? First period needs to be accounted, while last two needs to be escaped

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible as freemarker will treat 'name' as a property of 'variable'. So it is looking for an object called 'variable' first, which isn't there as it is named 'variable.name'

Comment: no it doesn't. Answer by @obourgain works for non nested variables